# Xcode 4.5.1 iOS5/5.1 IBAction not working. Fine in iOS6

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I'm having a bit of a problem when testing my app in iOS5/5.1. My IBAction from a button press just simply isn't getting called. I read somewhere that it could be because of gesture recognisers. I have this code which dismisses the keyboard when the user taps anywhere on the screen, and I think this might be the culprit. I also have a similar code in another screen but I can't even reach it to see if it's bugged similarly.

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *tapRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleSingleTap:)];
[tapRecognizer setDelegate:(id)self];
[tapRecognizer setNumberOfTapsRequired:1];
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:tapRecognizer];
```

And here is the function.

```
- (void)handleSingleTap:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)recognizer
{
    [self.searchBar resignFirstResponder];
}
```

How can I prevent this glitch from happening without losing the ability to dismiss the keyboard with a tap?

Regards,
Mike.

Comment: are you reusing an existing recognizer as there are bugs with that?

Comment: No, I don't think so. I made that explicitly for this function and have not used any other gesture recognisers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is the gesture recognizer recognising the tap and thus not delivering it to the button, which is a subview of the view to which the gesture recognizer is attached? You could try deleting the gesture recognizer once `handleSingleTap` has been called.

Comment: Nice fix. I used `[self.view removeGestureRecognizer:recognizer];` once everything has been done, and I only create the gesture in the didBeginEditing delegate method.

Comment: Thank you very much for the tick, and congratulations on overcoming yet another of the obstacles these blasted computer things put in our way!

Comment: You can use -(BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)touch. That is given by ios